# “Conversion failed” Error in a CTE

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012, common-table-expression

Here is a trimmed-down version of a SQL Server 2012 query I am using to get all users with age between 25 and 34 years. In my table,

1. The column "Feedback" is of type VarChar and stores the date of birth of a user as a VarChar in the format dd-mm-yyyy.
2. The column "FeedbackDate" is of type DateTime, and is basically the date on which the user told me his DOB in the form of a "feedback" which I store in the "Feedback" column.

---

```
WITH AgeCTE AS
    (
    SELECT
        CASE
            WHEN DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy, CONVERT(DATETIME, Feedback), FeedbackDate), CONVERT(DATETIME, Feedback)) < FeedbackDate
            THEN DATEDIFF(yy, CONVERT(DATETIME, Feedback), FeedbackDate)
        ELSE DATEDIFF(yy, CONVERT(DATETIME, Feedback), FeedbackDate) - 1
    END AS Age
    FROM FeedbackTable
    )
    SELECT COUNT(*) AS [25To34] FROM AgeCTE WHERE (Age >= 25) AND (Age <= 34)
```

On executing this query, I am getting the following error:

```
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.
```

Also, when I try to execute the inner query, it executes successfully which shows that the format of dates is not a problem till this inner query is executed.

For example, when I execute the following query:

```
SELECT
CASE
    WHEN DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy, CONVERT(DATETIME, Feedback), FeedbackDate), CONVERT(DATETIME, Feedback)) < FeedbackDate
    THEN DATEDIFF(yy, CONVERT(DATETIME, Feedback), FeedbackDate)
    ELSE DATEDIFF(yy, CONVERT(DATETIME, Feedback), FeedbackDate) - 1
    END AS Age
FROM FeedbackTable
```

I get an output as:

**Age**

23
33
35
8
etc...

Even the entire query with the CTE works if I omit the last WHERE clause. Specifically, if I remove the section

```
WHERE (Age >= 25) AND (Age <= 34)
```

and execute the following query:

```
WITH AgeCTE AS
(
    SELECT
        CASE
            WHEN DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy, CONVERT(DATETIME, Feedback), FeedbackDate), CONVERT(DATETIME, Feedback)) < FeedbackDate
            THEN DATEDIFF(yy, CONVERT(DATETIME, Feedback), FeedbackDate)
        ELSE DATEDIFF(yy, CONVERT(DATETIME, Feedback), FeedbackDate) - 1
    END AS Age
    FROM FeedbackTable
)
SELECT COUNT(*) AS [25To34] FROM AgeCTE
```

I get the following output:

**25To34**

9

I am not able to understand what the problem is with the WHERE clause. I read somewhere on the internet that it could be short-circuiting, but, I cannot figure it out how. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: "entire query" is working because you are not attempting to retrieve `Age` column hence it's ignored totally (not computed, because output of computation is useless). You have lots of conversions of `Feedback` field - what do you mean saying _you don't understand where is the problem_? The problem is with your data in `Feedback` column - some of values are not valid dates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you can use `ISDATE()` to check and see if the value can be converted. If not, then you can return a zero and that row will be excluded from your query.

```
WITH AgeCTE AS
(
  SELECT
    CASE
        WHEN DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy, CONVERT(DATETIME, Feedback), FeedbackDate), CONVERT(DATETIME, Feedback)) < FeedbackDate
        THEN DATEDIFF(yy, CONVERT(DATETIME, Feedback), FeedbackDate)
    ELSE 
      CASE 
        WHEN ISDATE(Feedback) = 1 
        THEN DATEDIFF(yy, CONVERT(DATETIME, Feedback), FeedbackDate) - 1
      ELSE
        0
      END
    END AS Age
  FROM FeedbackTable
)
SELECT COUNT(*) AS [25To34] 
FROM AgeCTE 
WHERE (Age >= 25) AND (Age <= 34)
```

I'll echo what @Shnugo said though, you should use an implicit format parameter to your `CONVERT` statements AND not use `VARCHAR` for storing dates.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.I had actually solved this last night by using exactly what you said - the ISDATE() function. But I'll give you credits by accepting your answer.

Answer (score 0):

First of all: It is always a bad idea to store date in string format...

Secondly: Your format `dd-mm-yyyy` is - even worse - culture specific. Using `CONVERT()` without the third parameter is gambling. Whether this works or not is depending on your system's settings.

As first try I'd add the appropriate code [Find details here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx):

```
CONVERT(DATETIME, Feedback, 105)
```

If you still get issues, you might use this (SQL-Server 2012+)

```
SELECT * 
FROM YourTable 
WHERE TRY_CONVERT(DATETIME,Feedback) IS NULL
```

`TRY_CONVERT` is a great rather new function, which returns NULL if the conversion fails.

Comment: `TRY_CONVERT` is a new fetcher for `SQL Server 2012` , The OP tags `SQL Server 2008` too.

Comment: @ahmedabdelqader, I know and have out the *2012+-hint* into my answer myself. It should be enough, to check the data integrity on a 2012+ server...

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I know storing dates in string format is not a good way. But the requirements of the system are such that it is nearly unavoidable to have it. I removed the error by using ISDATE() function in the query. It was a silly mistake that wasted hell lot of time. Thanks anyway!